# Replace just one line start of string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm new in sql and couldn't found how to change just firts line in a cell.

This is value of cell.

```
[B]Ynt: Hello I'm Jack[/B]

2 lines 
3 lines
4 lines
```

I want to change it to

```
2 lines 
3 lines
4 lines
```

Could you please help me for queries? Every first rows begin with [B]Ynt: and ending with [/B] There is one blank line after firts line. Check below pisture.

```
UPDATE xf_post SET message = REPLACE(message, 'Ynt:%', '');
```

[delete just first lines in a cell who has begin with "Ynt:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGeMn.png)

Comment: can not understand what do you want ?

Comment: I want to delete all lines is sql which is begin with "Ynt:" but just first line not whole cell.

Comment: show your sample data in a table

Comment: I added picture to my question  for what i need.

Comment: how to know your second line is start ?

Comment: [/b] only come one time in whole text ?

Comment: Good question. There is one blank line after this line like in example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this but on sample.

you can make **+3** as your need.

if you not understand let me know

```
 UPDATE xf_post SET 
    message =  REPLACE(message,SUBSTRING(message,1,POSITION( '[/b]' IN message)+3) , '') 
where message like "[b]Ynt:%"
```

I have just replace the message ="your given text" it is working as your desire result check it 
check below query

```
select REPLACE("[b]Ynt: 80'li yıllarda çocuk olmak..[/b] Yeğenim henüz dört yaşında.. [b][SIZE=16px]1990 lı olmakta böyleydi işte....[/SIZE][/b] 1980li yıllarda hayatının ilk tecrübelerini yaşamış, ilkokula gitmiş, Kenan Evren´i, Erdal İnönü´yü, Özal'ı tanımış olmak, Ajda Pekkan´ın Alo, Michael Jackson´ın Pepsi reklamlarını hatırlayacak kadar şanslı olmak demek.. [b]Türkiye'de yaşamış son mutlu kuşak olduğunu hüzünle hissetmek demek.. [/b] [b]Katılıyorum. 1990 lardada öyle[/b]",SUBSTRING("[b]Ynt: 80'li yıllarda çocuk olmak..[/b] Yeğenim henüz dört yaşında.. [b][SIZE=16px]1990 lı olmakta böyleydi işte....[/SIZE][/b] 1980li yıllarda hayatının ilk tecrübelerini yaşamış, ilkokula gitmiş, Kenan Evren´i, Erdal İnönü´yü, Özal'ı tanımış olmak, Ajda Pekkan´ın Alo, Michael Jackson´ın Pepsi reklamlarını hatırlayacak kadar şanslı olmak demek.. [b]Türkiye'de yaşamış son mutlu kuşak olduğunu hüzünle hissetmek demek.. [/b] [b]Katılıyorum. 1990 lardada öyle[/b]",1,POSITION( '[/b]' IN "[b]Ynt: 80'li yıllarda çocuk olmak..[/b] Yeğenim henüz dört yaşında.. [b][SIZE=16px]1990 lı olmakta böyleydi işte....[/SIZE][/b] 1980li yıllarda hayatının ilk tecrübelerini yaşamış, ilkokula gitmiş, Kenan Evren´i, Erdal İnönü´yü, Özal'ı tanımış olmak, Ajda Pekkan´ın Alo, Michael Jackson´ın Pepsi reklamlarını hatırlayacak kadar şanslı olmak demek.. [b]Türkiye'de yaşamış son mutlu kuşak olduğunu hüzünle hissetmek demek.. [/b] [b]Katılıyorum. 1990 lardada öyle[/b]")+3) , '')
```

Comment: 0 rows affected. Is that could be because of 'st' . There is no such a text in a cells. Every first cells begin with '[b]Ynt:' and ending with [/b]

Comment: ohhh sorry there is should be column name message

Comment: 0 rows affected. I tried [/b] and [/B]  lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: It's working but also delete every single line which are ending [/b] in a row. Is that possible to add it's begin wity '[b]Ytn:' By the way It's delete of next lines a few chracter.

Comment: give me your real text and i will let you now and want you want to delete

Comment: give me in text so i can test it

Comment: [b]Ynt: 80'li yıllarda çocuk olmak..[/b]

Yeğenim henüz dört yaşında..
[b][SIZE=16px]1990 lı olmakta böyleydi işte....[/SIZE][/b]

1980li yıllarda hayatının ilk tecrübelerini yaşamış, ilkokula gitmiş, 
Kenan Evren´i, Erdal İnönü´yü, Özal'ı tanımış olmak, 
Ajda Pekkan´ın Alo, Michael Jackson´ın Pepsi reklamlarını hatırlayacak 
kadar şanslı olmak demek.. 

[b]Türkiye'de yaşamış son mutlu kuşak olduğunu hüzünle hissetmek demek.. [/b] 
[b]Katılıyorum.
1990 lardada öyle[/b]

Comment: I just want to delete '[b]Ynt: 80'li yıllarda çocuk olmak..[/b]' first line in row.

Comment: Yes but it olsa delete if row begin like with '[b]Sample Text[/b]'                       Is that possible to make query like it wil begin with an '[b]Ynt:' ending with '[/b]'

Comment: yes u can put it in where condition see I have updated ans

Comment: UPDATE xf_post SET 
    message =  REPLACE(message,SUBSTRING(message,1,POSITION( '[/b]' IN message)+5) , '') 
where message like "[b]Ynt:%" worked wery well. Thanks alot for your patience and support.